# ag grid react: Can we have both client and server side filters?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have below queries ag grid react. I am exploring enterprise version

1. have combination filters like client side (grid data) and server (to request data from service). Any examples would help
2. does client row model support filters to call service?
3. does server side model support filters to do client search?

please advise

Comment: Hi guys, could you please help

Comment: hey  is this question not valid?

Comment: you can use either server side or client side filtering. the idea of using server side model is to deal with data consisting of multi-million rows. loading all that data slows the DOM and responsiveness.